# Looking for help to work out a subscription service schema

Tags: database, design-patterns, schema

I'm finding it difficult to decide on a schema for a monthly subscription service. In particular, if my the credit cards table should be related to the customer or to the subscription.

The tables I currently have are the following:

```
   users
      id
      other fields.

   addresses
      id
      userid
      other fields

   subscriptions
      id
      userid
      other fields

   cards
      id
      userid
      last4digits
```

A user can only have one subscription. For now, only credit cards are accepted as a form of payment. However, that could change in the future. My schema is simplistic, but I'm afraid my setup will be a pain to alter in the future if more payment types are added.

Can you provide me with some advice please?

Answer (score 1):

Your database design should consider what types of queries you will want to execute against the data, however, without knowing more, how about introducing a Payments table:

```
Clients 1..* Cards

Cards 1..* Payments

Payments 1..* Subscriptions
```

This way in the future you can easily add other payment types, e.g. add:

```
Clients 1..* PaypalAccounts

PaypalAccounts 1..* Payments
```

Also, I'm assuming a payment can be taken for more than one subscription.

Comment: thank you. When you write 1..* do you mean a one-to-many relationship?